# Rails 3.1.3 custom routing by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url

How to make path helpers for this route?

```
resources :news

match 'news/:year/:month/:day' => 'news#show',
    :constraints => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :day => /\d{2}/ },
    :as => 'newsdate'
```

I tried it many ways, but it not works:

```
link_to news.created_at.strftime '%d.%m.%Y ', newsdate_path(:year => '2011', :month => '11', :day => '11')
```

I get app error for this line by GET http://localhost:3000/news:

```
ArgumentError in News#index

    Showing /home/foxweb/work/dev/app/views/news/index.html.slim where line #6 raised:

    wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

How to make it right way?

P.S. http://localhost:3000/news/2011/11/11 works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, that's common mistake. You need to take `strftime` arguments in braces.

```
link_to news.created_at.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'), newsdate_path(:year => '2011', :month => '11', :day => '11')
```

That's all!

Comment: In other words, the error is occurring within link_to, not the route.

Comment: Ok, I do... but

Routing Error

`No route matches {:controller=>"news", :action=>"show", :year=>2004, :month=>9, :day=>15}`

Comment: Show us your `rake routes` output.

Comment: Oh, that's a typo in your RegEx. Must be `:month => /\d{1,2}/` for both variants: `:month => 9` or `:month => 12`. The same with the day: `:day => /\d{1,2}/`.

Comment: I think, now you can choose my answer as solution. :)